# Listbox: Event SelectedIndexChanged called when add one item

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have this code behind a winforms which simply has a listbox as its only control:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
listBox1.DataSource = dtv;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBox1.ValueMember = "IDName";
}
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataSet dss = UseDatabase.FillDataSet("Select * From Table Where IDName=" + listBox1.SelectedValue);
string st = dss.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
MessageBox.Show(st);
}
```

Run it say: "Additional information: There is no row at position 0."
Debug I see Event SelectedIndexChanged called when add one item.
Why user have not select item, that event is called
And how to fix this?

Comment: What is the value of SelectedIndex when your code hits that event handler? A bit of debug could reveal the problem

Comment: Hi, I set listBox1.ValueMember = "IDName"; on Form1_Load

Comment: From the error message you are getting you can make the conclusion that the query you are using returns no rows. Can you check with the debuger how exactly your query string looks like.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the only way for you to fix this is by checking that SelectedIndex != -1 before doing anything else on the event handler method.